# MFC CMenu and mouse wheel detection

Tags: c++, mfc

I have MFC popup tray menu (`CMenu`). Can I get mouse wheel messages for that `CMenu` popup menu?

How?
The popup tray menu is long and i want to use the mouse to scroll it.
I thought about catching the mouse wheel messages from the menu and simulate up/down - not sure how good idea is that ...

I tried to catch the app main windows events but it does not fire mouse wheel messages for that `CMenu`.

Comment: So you want the mouse wheel change the selection of the menu just like what happens when you move the mouse? Please [edit] and clarify. Read this: [ask]

Comment: I want to scroll the popup menu

Comment: You can't scroll menus with the mouse wheel. Anyway, long menus are terrible user experience

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.